# How to automatically click on the same button on all the browser tabs

Tags: browser, automation

Every day I need to open dozens of similar webpages, and click on the same button to save a file.

I suspect that the page is an Oracle Apex application, and it downloads a file from an SQL database.

It means that I cannot just copy the button hyperlink and automatize the download.

Is there any way to automatically click on the same button on all the tabs?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8eWER.png)

I can use any browser (generally I use Chrome of Firefox, but I can use another). I use Windows 10.

EDIT: The inspect tool in Chome on the button gives this code

```
<button class="btn btn-info pull-right" style="width:100px;" id="GenerarEXCEL" onclick="exportar(0)">Exportar</button>
```

Comment: Hi, all at the same time? I don't think there is a way. But secuencially of course there is. What programming languages are you familiar with? Saludos desde Chile.

Comment: @dmb I prefer VBA because I have the links in an Excel spreadsheet, but I can also use Visual Studio (VB or C#), Python, R.  I wrote here, because I hope this is a common problem, and it is already solved with some chrome/firefox extension, but code is also fine.

Comment: To some extent there are tools, but in you case I believe that you are going to need to code. You can achieve what you want with "Python+urllib3", "Python+Selenium", "Java+Selenium" or "C#+Selenium". You can do it in VBA but it doesn't worst the time. You can add a launcher to your spreadsheet and use it to lauch any batch or python script, throught cmd But this is not the place to discuss code. Try something then go to StackOverflow with some code and ask for help. Otherwise people will not be able to help you and will enforce the rules about asking questions.